# How can I order objects by price in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have tried to sort the list of objects based on the price of each individual object has. However, I have got this error `the expression here has a type of void, and therefore it cannot be used`

```
class Item{
  String productName;
  double price;
}

List<Item> items = ...;

items.sort((a, b) => a.price.compareTo(b.price));
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error is reported on the `item.sort(...)` line?  Are you sure that you didn't omit any relevant details? (For example, can you confirm that you aren't doing something like `items = items.sort(...)`?)

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

[List.sort](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/List/sort.html) modifies the object on which it is call. It doesn't return any value and you have to use the original list.

```
var list = [3, 1, 2];
list.sort();
print(list); // displays [1, 2, 3]
```

If you want to inline the `.sort()` to use the list directly, you can use the [cascade notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-):

```
var list = [3, 1, 2]..sort();
print(list); // displays [1, 2, 3]

// or 
var list = [3, 1, 2];
print(list..sort()); // displays [1, 2, 3]
```